# interactive communication console programs(like client-server) windows

Tags: windows, console, interactive

I have two console programs (ex. first - client, second - server).
Do Windows have a command or resource to connect it?

Client ask question, Server answer.

Anyone encountered this problem? (just win)

Comment: I didn't understood your question; what are you trying to accomplish and what language are you using?

Comment: I'm not writing a program. I have 2 *.exe, and they should work together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows have pipes :

dir | sort

| sends data from one program to another via usual IO.

Bidirectial transfers are not that simple, unfortunately.

If you need bi-dir, you'll have to mess around sockets and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Client - Server is a programming model. As you are refering to **programs** and not scripts, this means you have to applications and you are simply have two corresponding windows instead of UI. You should look into interprocess communication, or tcp server-client, etc. in whichever lanuage you use.

//if I understood fully what you mean :)